# Online reindexing in Gerrit 2.11

Tags: lucene, gerrit

I want to upgrade Gerrit 2.10 to 2.11.1.

Gerrit is hosted on Tomcat 7 and is using MySQL 5.6 on Windows 7.
The documentation of Gerrit 2.11 mentions that if the index version of LUCENE is 11 [which is the same in my case], online reindexing could be used to reduce the downtime of Gerrit.

While running `java -jar gerrit-2.11.war init -d <gerrit_site>`, I still get the prompt to run reindex before launching Gerrit.

- How do I reindex online?
- I have a huge list of Git repos with years of closed reviews and also many open reviews. I do not want to spend hours reindexing gerrit offline. Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Anantha

Comment: Did the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/yBn0UwaKvp4/ku8q4ON8fc0J) that you got through the repo-discuss list (*Gerrit will reindex in the background automatically at restart*) work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Since [version 2.11.2](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.2/cmd-index-start.html), you can start online reindexing using `gerrit index start` SSH command.